# Incorrect PHP Parse Error?

Tags: php, linux, apache, nginx

I have a php script that I've used many times. However each time has been on  a server administered through cpanel.

This time I have a fresh CentOS 6.3 install, apache and php. When I try to run the script I get a:

```
[Sat Feb 22 08:19:09 2014] [error] [client 105.228.246.70] PHP Parse error:  syntax         
error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING in /var/www/html/1/install.php on line     
125
```

The weird part is that the .php works fine if it's a fresh install with cpanel and uploaded via the cpanel file manager.

php is working as confirmed by phpinfo()

Things I've tried:

- downloading the .php script via wget also ftp in ascii and binary mode
- changing ownership between root/apache
- fresh install using nginx + php-fpm - exactly the same error
- installing various php extensions that are present after a cpanel install

Other possible ideas that I haven't managed to fully try:

- matching the apache and php versions on the fresh install to the cpanel install that works

line 124 - 132 of the code in question:

```
    $data = "<?php
    \$userId = '{$_REQUEST['username']}';
    \$passWord = '{$_REQUEST['password']}';
    define('APIKEY','{$_REQUEST['apikey']}');
    define('APISECRET','{$_REQUEST['apisecret']}');
    define('GO_PATH','{$_REQUEST['gopath']}');
    define('ADMIN_PATH','{$_REQUEST['adminpath']}');
    define('LOC_CAMP','{$_REQUEST['campaignpath']}');
    define('LOC_LOG','{$_REQUEST['logspath']}');\n?>";
```

Comment: check the versions of the php and the exntesions as well

Comment: This line of code works fine with my PHP. Actually the error message does not make sense. Are you sure you are looking at the correct file and the correct line and provided it as-is?

Comment: Another possibility would be that there is a syntax error way above your line, which breaks parsing just in this line (i.e. a missing quote). Any editor with moderate syntax highlighting should show this to you in very obvious way (all above has the same color).

Comment: @GhostGambler - just triple checked by downloading from the server and looking at it locally + using vim and checking it out on the server using the path of the error. Ran through phpcodechecker, did come out with two extra {{. This only makes sense if characters were added/removed automatically somehow

Comment: Maybe you had the file opened, wanted to type or delete some characters in another window, but your cursor was accidentally in the code window? When you tried to close the document, you have been asked if you wanted to save your changes, you were unsure and said "Yes" -> file changed.

Comment: Do not know how, but this line works, and this is not the error. Look above. Look around. There is an error somewhere.